# Комбинации с Compose клавишей для строк

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Согласно мануалу https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ComposeKey, можно определять комбинации клавиш не только для символов, но и для строк. Например, так:

```
<Multi_key> <b> <t> <w> : "by the way" # Compose b t w
```

Это работало когда-то раньше, но в 18.04 Убунте не работает.
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На launchpad открыт баг репорт [1845332](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1845332) про эту проблему.
<s>Приглашаю всех пострадавших и сочувствующих  зайти туда и отметиться в затронутых.</s>…

**Upd:** На баг репорт получен ответ.

**Как сделать, чтобы заработали комбинации со строками (Ubuntu 18.04):**

- Открыть `Параметры  → Регион и язык → Управления установленными языками →(вкладка Языки)`
- Переключить `Метод ввода с клавиатуры` на `XIM`.
- Закрыть
- Перезагрузить.

Это решение предположительно должно работать и для других дистрибутивов, основанных на Ubuntu.

**Объяснение:**

Ubuntu может использовать для ввода с клавиатуры [XIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Input_Method) (X Input Method) или [IBus](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBus) (Intelligent Input Bus).
XIM — старинный модуль, разработан еще для X (X Window System). Если/когда Ubuntu перейдет с иксов на Wayland, с ним окончательно расстанутся.
А сейчас `Метод ввода с клавиатуры` по умолчанию ставят `IBus`, т.к. на нем работает GNOME (GUI версии 18.04). Если выбран `IBus`, то комбинациями клавиш с Compose занимается GTK, а он не умеет вставлять строки. Это как бы не баг IBus-а, а  feature  GTK. Чинить это не будут.
При этом XIM в Ubuntu тоже имеет какие-то проблемы, которые тоже чинить не будут.

Короче, выбирайте метод ввода, в котором меньше проблем лично для вас. Ибо нет совершенства в мире.

Comment: дык, баг закрыт... смысл на него подписываться?.. можно написать в апстрим ibus'а и gtk... также можешь сюда воркараунд оттуда переписать...